# DDD, Databases and Lists of Data

Tags: database, list, domain-driven-design

Im at the beginning of my first "real" software project, and I'd like to start off right. The concept of DDD seems like a very clean approach which separates the various software parts, however im having trouble implementing this in reality.

My Software is measurement tracker and essentially stores list of measurement data, consisting of a timestamp and the data value.

My Domain Models

```
class MeasurementDM{
   string Name{get;set;}
   List<MeasurementPointDM> MeasurementPoints{get;set;}
}

class MeasurementPointDM{
   DateTime Time{get;set;}
   double Value{get;set;}
}
```

My Persistence Models:

```
class MeasurementPM{
   string Id{get;set;} //Primary key
   string Name{get;set;} //Data from DomainModel to store
}

class MeasurementPointPM{
   string Id{get;set;} //Primary Key
   string MeasurementId{get;set;} //Key of Parent measurement
}
```

I now have the following issues:

1) Because I want to keep my Domain Models pure, I don't want or need the Database Keys inside those classes. This is no problem when building my Domain models from the Database, but I don't understand how to store them, as the Domain Model no longer knows the Database Id. Should I be including this in the Domain model anyway? Should I create a Dictionary mapping Domain objects to Database ids when i retreive them from the Database?

2)The measurement points essentially have the same Id problem as the measurements themselves. Additionally I'm not sure what the right way is to store the MeasurementPoints themselves. Above, each MeasurementPointPM knows to which MeasurementPM it belongs. When I query, I simply select MeasurementPoints based on their Measurement key. Is this a valid way to store such data? It seems like this will explode as more and more measurements are added. Would I be better off serializing my list of MeasurementPoints to a string, and storing the whole list as an nvarchar? This would make adding and removing datapoints more difficult, as Id always need to deserialize, reserialize the whole list

I'm having difficulty finding a good example of DDD that handles these problems, and hopefully someone out there can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

> My Software is measurement tracker and essentially stores list of measurement data, consisting of a timestamp and the data value.

You may want to have a careful think about whether you are describing a service or a database.  If your primary use case is storing information that comes from somewhere else, then introducing a domain model into the mix may not make your life any better.

Domain models test to be interesting when new information interacts with old information.  So if all you have are data structures, it's going to be hard to discover a good model (because the critical element -- how the model entities change over time -- is missing).

That said....

> I don't understand how to store them, as the Domain Model no longer knows the Database Id.

This isn't your fault.  The literature sucks.

The most common answer is that _people are allowing their models to be polluted with O/RM concerns.  For instance, if you look at the [Cargo](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/domain/model/cargo/Cargo.java#L187) entity from the Citerus sample application, you'll find these lines hidden at the bottom:

```
Cargo() {
    // Needed by Hibernate
}

// Auto-generated surrogate key
private Long id;
```

This is an indirect consequence of the fact that the "repository" pattern provides the illusion of an in-memory collection of *objects* that maintain their own state, when the reality under the covers is that you are copying *values* between memory and durable storage.

Which is to say, if you want a clean domain model, then you are going to need a separate in memory representation for your stored data, and functions to translate back and forth between the two.

Put another way, what you are running into is a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle -- if you are using the same types to model your domain that you use to manage your persistence, the result is going to be a mix of the two concerns.

> So essentially you would say that some minimal pollution of the domain model, for example an Id, is standard practice.

Less strong; I would say that it is a *common* practice.  Fundamentally, a lot of people, particularly in the early stages of a project, don't value having a [boundary](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries) between their domain model and their persistence plumbing.

> Could it make sense to have every Domain Model inherit from a base class or implement an interface that forces the creation of Unique Id?

It could.  There are a *lot* of examples on the web where domain entities extend some generic `Entity` or `Aggregate` pattern.

The really interesting questions are

- What are the immediate costs and benefits of doing that?
- What are the deferred costs and benefits of doing that?

In particular, does that make things easier or harder to change?

Comment: So essentially you would say that some minimal pollution of the domain model, for example an Id, is standard practice. So I would have a MeasurementDM (Domain Model) which has an Id, which can be translated into a MeasurementPM (Persistence Model) which itself can be easily stored in a database. Could it make sense to have every Domain Model inherit from a base class or implement an interface that forces the creation of Unique Id?

Comment: @ClaudeHasler have you considered a client generated key such as a GUID/UUID? This will allow you to worry less about keys in your persistence layer and instead speak about the "identity" of an aggregate.